# Using Laravels Eloquent with database views

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, view

I have two database tables, **expenses** and **incomes** and I created a MySQL view, **transactions**, which basically is an UNION between the two tables, selecting the fields I am interested in.

The **transactions** view contains the following columns:

- transaction_id
- user_id
- amount
- note
- transaction_type
- updated_at
- created_at

I created an Eloquent Model for the view, called Transactions.

The problem is when I want to retrieve transactions based on certain criteria. 
E.g. I want to get all transactions for a User. Normally, if transactions was a table, I would define a foreign key relationship and I would simply call `$user->hasMany('App\Models\Transaction')`.

Since foreign keys are not possible for views, I tried using the 'where' method: `Transaction::where('user_id', $user->id)`. This query does not return anything, neither do any other queries I tested. The only method that returned data is `Transaction::all()`, but this doesn't help me very much.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you wanna get the user information with your query?

Comment: No, I want to get all the transactions with a specific user_id. Let's say the user id is 3, the equivalent query would be `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = 3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For where statement in Eloquent you must to end up with get, try this:

```
$transactions = Transaction::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

Comment: Transaction::where('user_id', $user->id) return relationship between tables, and Transaction::where('user_id', $user->id)->get() return a Collections of objects :-)